What happens if you have 208 V 115 A transformer on a 150 A breaker and you put it on a 100 A breaker? Breaker to transformer to machine
What happens if put a 115 A transformer on a 100 A breaker?

On a 100 A breaker if the load draws above 100 A the breaker will trip.
On a 150 A breaker the transformer can be railed to its max rating (115 A), the output circuit will be limited at 115 A max and the breaker is only there to protect the downstream circuit from something extreme/catastrophic happening to the transformer above 150 A. Also the 150 A breaker will happily burn up the transformer if something weird/wrong is happening at the range between 116 A and 149 A without tripping the 150 A breaker.

The other answer is exactly correct. Also to remember is that just because you have a 115 amp transformer does not mean that the load is always 115 amp.
You probably have a breaker box with a number of circuits that are all individually fused. If the transformer drives only a single load then the 100 amp breaker is better than the 150 amp.

Will it damage the transformer in anyway if I lower the breaker to 100 amp !  The breaker that feeds the transformer only pulls 70 amps when I meters it

So, if you install a 100 amp breaker to feed the transformer and the transformer maximum load is 70 amps things will work fine. What you have to protect against is a massive short circuit downstream from the transformer. An 80 amp breaker at the load fuse box will protect things from the fuse box down. That only leaves the connection from the transformer to the fuse box. If that connection shorts the 100 amp breaker will protect the transformer.
