Will it damage a transformer if I lower the breaker to the size down if the machine doesn’t pull more than the lower breaker size
I have a  transformer on 150 breaker that feeds a 125 amp fused disconnect that feeds a cnc machine.   I metered the breaker it never pulled more than 70 amps at the breaker.   I need to use the 150 breaker for a new can machine.  If I put the transformer on a 100 breaker will it do any damage to the transformer that is rated at 115 amps 208 volts to a 100 amp breaker.  I metered the breaker that feed the transformer and it never pulled more than 65 amps per phase.

A superset of this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/726994/what-happens-if-you-have-208-v-115-a-transformer-on-a-150-a-breaker-and-you-put

what type of meter was used to establish that "it never pulled more than 65 amps"? A multimeter isn't nearly fast enough to determine that there were no inrush spikes...


Will it damage a transformer if I lower the breaker to the size down if the machine doesn’t pull more than the lower breaker size[?]

No.
What would damage the transformer is if your load pulled too much current, or if your primary voltage was too high, or your frequency was too low, or if you physically attacked it with a sledge hammer etc.. However, lowering the trip point of the breaker will do none of those things.
However, be aware that start-up current for a machine or a transformer can be much higher than the "nameplate" value. Thus, it is possible that using a breaker with a lower trip point will cause the breaker to trip when starting your machine. That would be annoying, but it shouldn't damage your transformer.

Nuisance trips like that can be indirectly dangerous, because they can lead people to bypass fuses (every electrician comes across a fuse socket with a coin stuck in it at least once!). Breakers in a breaker panel are harder to bypass, though, so I think the risk is lower.

It will not hurt the transformer. What might hurt is damaging the CNC machine from false nuisance trips during power-up because some electricians did not know anything about breaker/fuse coordination or NEC 430 and 450, which cover the requirements of transformers and motor machinery.
If you want to know what size and type of breaker your CNC machine requires, look it up in the operations manual or consult a licensed electrician or engineer.
